CMake cannot find a package configuration file "libpqxx-config.cmake" that is here, at its expected place in the build directory?
My CMake build preparation cannot find a package configuration file
(run below with few of its --trace-expand values)
cmake -S . -B ./build/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

/workspaces/template-cpp/CMakeLists.txt(2):  project(CPPTemplate)
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(1):  set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM Linux-5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(2):  set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(3):  set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(4):  set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64 )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(8):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM Linux-5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(9):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(10):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(11):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86_64 )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(13):  set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING FALSE )
/workspaces/template-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/3.29.5/CMakeSystem.cmake(15):  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_LOADED 1 )
[...]
/workspaces/template-cpp/CMakeLists.txt(5):  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 )
/workspaces/template-cpp/CMakeLists.txt(9):  set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ./build/Release/generators/ )
/workspaces/template-cpp/CMakeLists.txt(16):  include_directories(./src )
/workspaces/template-cpp/CMakeLists.txt(17):  add_subdirectory(src )
/workspaces/template-cpp/src/CMakeLists.txt(3):  find_package(libpqxx REQUIRED )
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findlibpqxx.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "libpqxx", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libpqxx" with any
  of the following names:

    libpqxxConfig.cmake
    libpqxx-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libpqxx" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libpqxx_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libpqxx" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.

But the file is where, I think, it is expected:
$ ls ./build/Release/generators/libpqxx-config.cmake
./build/Release/generators/libpqxx-config.cmake

Even changing CMAKE_MODULE_PATH for an absolute path /workspaces/template-cpp/build/Release/generators/ is unsuccessful.
What have I misconfigured? Am I setting wrong variables to run it?

libpqxx-config.cmake is a configuration file. When search this file, CMake does NOT take into account variable CMAKE_MODULE_PATH. (Read the error messages carefully: the variable could help to find Findlibpqxx.cmake script only.) A configuration file normally is shipped with the other project, so build directory of the currently built project doesn't look a proper place for such file. Have you ever installed libpqxx?

@Tsyvarev Yes, through a conan install . -b=missing -s compiler.cppstd=gnu17 --settings=build_type=Release. Currently, it responds: libpqxx/7.8.1: Already installed! (16 of 31)

If you are using conan you should also use its toolchain/preset file when generating and building.

@Botje conan generates a toolchain. I can check its presence by an ls and specify it: cmake -S . -B ./build/ -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./build/Release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release but it has no effect.

Not generating the conan files under the build directory but eg in conan works for me.
